# Run Xcode build remotely and get results back to run the project locally or show build issues

Tags: xcode, bash, command-line, build, compilation

Building can be a heavy task for a not-very-powerful computer. That said, would there be a way to setup a server so that it builds an Xcode project and then returns the results to the local machine so that it runs the compiled project on a simulator or show the build issues (if any) within Xcode itself?

Answer (score 1):

I had done some Xcode work, GUI mode, before I found the xcodebuild command, which runs your Xcode project build from the command line (OSX terminal/XQuartz.

You could try mounting your build environment (nfs et al), read/write, on a more powerful machine (bigger mac?), then use xcodebuild there, then put your app through its paces in the simulator on the less powerful machine.

You would have to make sure that the more powerful machine does not implicitly apply configuration parameters to your project that are not valid on the less powerful machine.

This would only help if the difference in machine powers had a greater effect than the overhead of mounting protocols.